# Function in LuCI project

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

Here is a code block in LuCI ([OpenWrt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) web UI) project.

I don't understand what this function is doing, and I am unable to find where it is called. Where is this function being called and what it is doing?

```
p = s:option(ListValue, "proto", translate("Protocol"))
p.override_values = true

p:value("pppoe", "PPPoE") 
p:value("pptp",  "PPTP")  

function p.write(self, section, value)
    if value == "pptp" or value == "pppoe" then
        self.map:set(section, "peerdns", "1")
        self.map:set(section, "defaultroute", "1")
    end
    return ListValue.write(self, section, value)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `p.write(self, section, value)` is overriding the abstract parent method. LuCI is an MVC, so Listvalue calls the write function when the page appling automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where it is being called, but I assume from a network configuration LuCI web page.

It writes to the UCI Network configuration file (logically, a commit is needed for physical write).

## References

- *[Network configuration](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network)*
- *[UCI (Unified Configuration Interface) – Technical Reference](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/uci#lua.bindings.for.uci)* (search for `x:set`)